# 名詞の修飾と「～か」・「～かどうか」についての質問

Tags: grammar

日本語の名詞を修飾する時、「が」しか使えないでしょう？

例えば、

> 私**が**いつも遊んでいたところはあの川の傍の公園です。
>   友達**が**買ってくれたパソコンはこれだ。

今私の質問は、～か／～かどうか　についてはそういう文法がありますか？？

そして、そういう思いの上で文を書いてみました（英語で同じ意味を表してみました、意味は正しくないなら　是非教えてくださいね）：

> あなた**は**何をしているかを知っている。 "**You** know what you are doing."
>
> あなた**が**何をしているかを知っている。 "**I** know what you are doing."

以上の文の意味は違うのでしょう？？　違うのなら何処が違うかを教えてください。

質問が多くてすみません。

Comment: 日本語で答えたほうがよろしいですか？

Comment: Your question is 1) whether the 主語 of 連体形 should be followed by “が”, 2) whether this also apply to a clause ending with “か”, and 3) whether and why using “は” instead of “が” in a clause changes the meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 日本語の名詞を修飾する時、「が」しか使えないでしょう？

これは完全に正確だと言えません。連体修飾句では、一般的には「が」が使われていますが、「は」も可能です：`あれは［私には役に立たない］方法だ。`こういう場合には、「は」が対比を表します。

> 以上の文の意味は違うのでしょう？？

注釈は間違ってはいませんが、他の意味も可能です。

簡単に言うと、両文に二つの構造があります。その上に、「は」も「が」も複数の意味を持っています。主語が決まっているわけでもありません。したがって、意味はたくさんあります。

- > **文１構造１**：あなた**は**［（○が）何をしているか］を知っている。
  >   　普通の「は」："You know what (you/I/he/she/X) is doing."
  >   　対比を表す「は」："*You* know what (you/I/he/she/X) is doing (but someone else doesn't)."

  「あなたは」が主節にある場合。
- > **文１構造２**：（○は）［あなた**は**何をしているか］を知っている。
  >   　対比を表す「は」："(You/I/he/she/X) knows what *you* are doing (but not someone else.)"

  「あなたは」が埋め込み文にある場合。（ご注意：文脈があっても、この解釈はほぼ不可能です。）
- > **文２構造１**：あなた**が**［（○が）何をしているか］を知っている。
  >   　何かを特定する「が」："*You* are the one who knows what (you/I/he/she/X) is doing."

  「あなたが」が主節にある場合。
- > **文２構造２**：（○は）［あなた**が**何をしているか］を知っている。
  >   　普通の「が」："(You/I/he/she/X) knows what you are doing."
  >   　何かを特定する「が」："(You/I/he/she/X) knows what *you* are doing."

  「あなたが」が埋め込み文にある場合。

Comment: ”（○は）［あなたは何をしているか］を知っている。
「あなたは」が埋め込み文にある。”
どうしてこの使い方は不可能ですか？？　やはり「は」は埋め込み文の中で使えませんか？

Comment: 一般的に言えば、埋め込み文では「は」が使えます。例：「彼は来ないと思います。」（対比を表します。）でも「〜か」の場合は、なかなか変に聞こえます。少なくとも、私は自然に聞こえる文を思い付かないです。

Comment: じゃ　「〜かどうか」の場合は埋め込み文の中で「は」が使えますか？？
質問が多くてすみません。

Comment: その場合も使えないと思います。「彼は来るかどうか分かりません。」という文章は言えますが、これは「彼は、［（私に彼が）来るかどうか分かりません］。 」という意味になります。

Comment: すみません。誤解のないように言うと、↑の完全な構造は「彼は［［（彼が）来るかどうか］（私に）分かりません］。」ということです。

Comment: broccoliさんの例文は"He doesn't know if he will come or not. "という意味ですか？

Comment: @vincentlin いいえ、"I don't know if he will come or not."という意味だと思います。「彼」は構造的には主節にありますが、意味的には、「来る」の動作主になると思います。